# Renderer2 - remove nativeElement in directive

Tags: angular, directive

in my component, I have a for-loop with an option-element with a directive. Now i check in the directive if data is available, if no i will remove the ngOption Element from DOM. But this is not working... I see still empty elements in the optionlist.
[image]

> this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');

component.ts

```
<ng-select id="event1" style="width: 400px; padding-top: 12px" class="ml-2"
 (change)="search()" [{(ngModel)]="selectedEvent" [disabled]="blockedActionWhileLoading">
  <div *ngFor="let event of events">
    <ng-option appEventFilter [event]="event">
    </ng-option>
  </div>
</ng-select>
```

directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { TicketState } from 'src/app/tickets/ticket.model';
import { TicketService } from 'src/app/tickets/ticket.service';
import { Event } from 'src/app/verwaltung/events/event.model';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appEventFilter]',
})
export class EventFilterDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() event: Event;

  constructor(
    private ticketService: TicketService,
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private datePipe: DatePipe
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let t = this.ticketService.tickets.filter(
      (ticket) =>
        ticket.event._id === this.event._id && ticket.state === TicketState.NEW
    );

    if (t.length > 0) {
      let datePipeTimeString = this.datePipe.transform(
        this.event.date,
        'HH:mm'
      );
      let datePipeDateString = this.datePipe.transform(this.event.date);
      this.renderer.setProperty(
        this.el.nativeElement,
        'innerHTML',
        `${this.event.artist.name} - ${this.event.location.city} -
        ${this.event.location.description} -
                         ${datePipeDateString} -
                         ${datePipeTimeString}
                        `
      );
    } else {
      console.log('empty');
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try this insted ? ```this.view.clear();```  inject this ```private view: ViewContainerRef```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would only render those entries which contain valid data by either filtering them before you write the values in `events` or with an pipe.

The pipe solution could be the most interesting solutions here because it doesn't modify the original array

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filterEvents' })
export class FilterEventsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private ticketService: TicketService){}

  // I only assume that the type is Ticket
  transform(tickets: Ticket[]): Ticket[] {
 
    const filteredTickets = tickets.filter(ticket => {
      return this.ticketService.tickets.some(
        t => t.event.__id === ticket.event._id && t.state === TicketState.NEW
      );
    });
    return filteredTickets;

  }

}
```

And then use the pipe as following:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events | filterEvents ">
  <ng-option appEventFilter [event]="event"></ng-option>
</div>
```

With this way you're not only solving your problem with the empty entries, you're also reducing the number of `div`s on your page because you're only rendering the entries which contain relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

@Batajus

thanks... this is a good solution!... I has to change the Value from Tickets to Events (EventFilter)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Ticket, TicketState } from 'src/app/tickets/ticket.model';
import { TicketService } from 'src/app/tickets/ticket.service';
import { Event } from 'src/app/verwaltung/events/event.model';

@Pipe({ name: 'filterEvents' })
export class FilterEvents2Pipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private ticketService: TicketService) {}

  // I only assume that the type is Ticket
  transform(events: Event[], tickets: Ticket[]): Event[] {
    if (!events) return;
    const filteredEvents = events.filter((e) => {
      return tickets.some((ticket) => {
        return ticket.event._id == e._id && ticket.state == 'NEW';
      });
    });

    return filteredEvents;
  }
}
```

Another question... what is faster...
ngIf or a directive?
I have a huge list of Data an a lot ngIf's in html.
It is better to make a directive for all that?

```
 *ngIf="
  ticket.state === TicketState.BILLED ||
  ticket.state === TicketState.BILLEDEX ||
  ticket.state === TicketState.WRITTENOFF"
```